# Shedding list layers - Python

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array

How could you turn:

```
[[["hi"], ["hello"]]]
```

into:

```
[["hi"], ["hello"]]
```

While also working with [] as an input

Comment: try `flattened = [val for sublist in list_of_lists for val in sublist]`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `pop` function to take the first item out of the list.

```
>>> a = [["hi"]]
>>> a = a.pop(0)
>>> a
['hi']
```

Or you can also do something like:

```
>>> a = [["hi"]]
>>> a = a[0]
>>> a
['hi']
```

As you edited your question:

```
>>> a = [[["hi"], ["hello"]]]
>>> a = a.pop(0)
>>> a
[['hi'], ['hello']]
```

If you have an empty list:

```
a = []
try:a = a.pop(0) #try if it don't raises an error
except:pass  #if error is raised, ingnore it
```

So , according to the code above, if the list is empty , it will not raise any error.

If you want it to be more simpler:

```
a = []
if len(a) != 0:a = a[0] 
print(a)
```

You can also make a function to make it simple to use with empty or non-empty lists:

```
def get(list):
    return list if len(list) == 0 else list[0]
```

Testing our function:

```
>>> get([])
[]
>>> get([["Hi","Bye"]])
['Hi', 'Bye']
```

Comment: Actually it doesn't work for an empty list which is a problem

Comment: @user236529 What do you mean by an empty list?

Comment: the empty list []

Answer (score 1):

You can use a nested list comprehension to flatten it:

```
list_of_lists = [['hi'],['hello']]
flattened = [val for sublist in list_of_lists for val in sublist]
print(flattened)
```

This also works if you have multipe sublists in your list.
You can read more about this on [python's documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use `itertools`

```
import itertools
ip = [["hi"]]
op = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(ip))
# op ["hi"]
```

Or a numpy solution using [ravel](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html#numpy-ravel)

```
import numpy as np
ip = [["hi"]]
ip = np.array(ip)
op = list(ip.ravel())
```

Since you edited your question, you only want n-1 dimensions, you could use [np.transpose](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) -

```
ip = [[["hi"], ["hello"]]]
op = ip.transpose().reshape(2, 1)
```

You could check if your input is empty`[]` explicitly before doing any operations on it, that way to avoid errors -

```
if ip:
    # do some operations on ip
```